# What database should I use to create a webmail service like gmail?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, mongodb

I planned to use python for my frontend with django framework.

But for backend, I have no idea which database I should use.

Since it involves plenty of reads and writes can someone point me in the correct direction?

By the way I read it in [this blog](http://dieswaytoofast.blogspot.in/2012/09/mysql-vs-postgres-vs-mongodb.html) like this

```
MySQL is what you get when application developers build an RDBMS. 
PostgreSQL is what you get when database developers build an application development platform. 
MongoDB is what you get when GUI developers build an RDBMS.
```

Comment: Downvoted because you just posted the same thing on Stack Overflow (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20866724/what-database-should-i-use-to-create-a-webmail-service-like-gmail_, ignored the comments there, and re-posted here. You're not taking the message. We can't design your system for you, and this kind of thing is just too broad for a simple Q&A site.

Comment: Oh, and really, what you should do is use an established IMAP server as a back-end for mail storage and management (Dovecot, Cyrus IMAPd, etc etc), then overlay features you want in your web based mail client. Look at RoundCube, SquirrelMail, etc.

Comment: ^ and choose a distributed filesystem for scalability, and ensure that your frontend is restful so you can have different servers serving the frontend. (angularjs would be my recommendation for building the frontend)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I second Craig Ringer's recommendation of IMAP.  It's already got all the [relevant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321) [standards](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322) built in.

If you're determined to proceed with creating a webmail client/email server architecture written as a web client with a database server rather than pre-written email server back end, I'd look at how Exchange has historically handled mail databases.  Example links include [this description of 5.5 (old)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/271987), [this newer description](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996118%28v=exchg.65%29.aspx), and [this overview](https://www.simple-talk.com/sysadmin/exchange/exchange-database-technologies/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually this email project is going to be my startup. I have 3 years programming experience in PHP and MySQL. But never worked with MongoDB and PostgreSQL. I don't wanna go back and do everything from the beginning. Thats why I'm asking this question to choose the perfect database for my email startup. Let me rephrase my question. `If you are going to start a webmail service like gmail, yahoomail or hotmail which database would you choose?`

Comment: Any answer I give you will just be my personal taste.  So I'm going to defer to Brent Ozar's answer on StackOverflow here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205534/database-for-enormous-amounts-of-data/215890#215890

Comment: After reading Brent Ozar's answer,I guess I better use MySQL.Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

On a similar project I simply went with [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) for its full-text search. Email doesn't really need all the relational features of MySQL or other relational databases.